# Could information be transferred through a wormhole?

Tags: general-relativity, faster-than-light, information, qft-in-curved-spacetime, wormholes

There was a [paper published recently](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/get-messages-sent-through-wormhole-relativity) about the possibility of sending messages through a wormhole,[see reference here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.106.104054). It has also been speculated that any entangled pair of particles—even particles not ordinarily considered to be black holes, and pairs of particles with different masses or spin, or with charges which aren't opposite—are connected by Planck scale wormholes  [see reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER_%3D_EPR). We also know that [quantum reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_reflection) involves [the Casimir - Polder interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect). Putting these things together,  is it possible that the  wedge-modified path-entangled EPR experiment with variable entanglement in [the Herbert - Cramer paper, section 6](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5098) might have something to do with these phenomena ? The signal is very weak, but a statistical reproduction of the experiment could in principle detect such a signal, see figure 8 in the Herbert-Cramer paper. I realize the question is highly speculative,but I am interested in a hunch, not a full complete answer,  coming from someone with proper expertise in the physics involved, which I don't have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your 1. and 2. link they require ghost matter, which is unphysical. Nevertheless, if you had enough of this ghost material you could compensate for the collapsing effect real matter would have on the wormhole.

So you could either send a ghost particle through without risking to collapse the throat, or send a real particle accompanied by one or two ghost particles. Since there is no ghost matter in this universe that won't work for real though.

Your 1. link is amateur nonsense by the way, since they claim *"Theoretically, ghost matter responds to gravity in exactly the opposite way to normal matter. That is, a ghost matter apple would fall up from a tree branch instead of down. While allowed by Einstein’s theory of general relativity..."* which is wrong since gravity is not a force but geometry.

Relativity only allows for (also unphysical) [negative matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/394414/24093) which itself is gravitationally repulsive, but an apple made of negative matter would still be attracted to the earth while slightly repelling the earth, which in the case of opposite masses with the same magnitude would lead to the formation of a so called [runaway pair](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/256646/24093).